# Numerical method for space fractional derivative in 1 dimension

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-calculus, fractional-calculus, fractional-differential-equations

I am very new to the subject of fractional derivatives which arise while characterizing the anomalous transport of passive scalar in turbulence.

I have found an equation of the following form, to describe such anomalous transport, which I have to solve numerically,
$$\partial_{t}f(x,t)=kD^{\alpha}_{|x|}f(x,t)+g(x,t)$$
where $k$ is some constant, $D^{\alpha}_{|x|}$ is symmetric Riesz fractional derivative of order $\alpha$ and $g(x,t)$ is a source/sink term.
The numerical algorithm that I can find are too mathematically abstract for me,
therefore it would be of great help if anyone could sketch out the basic ideas behind constructing numerical algorithms for such equations.

Comment: You may find more specialized help on https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion. I do not know why did not I post it there earlier.